# TCP Sockets: recv() not receiving my full data

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a problem regarding a client/server TCP application.

I need it to do the following things:

- The transferred file should be sent in packages of no more than 1460 bytes.
- The client should ask for the name of the file to transfer then connect to the server, send a struct containing size, quantity of packages to send and file name. Wait for the server to send back the same struct as a handshake to check if everything was received ok. If the received one is the same it will start sending all the packages. After that, once again send the struct to inform that everything was sent and wait for the server response.
- The server should wait for a connection, then create a child to manage it. It should send back the struct received containing the file information, start saving the packages received in a file with the same name as indicated and stop after receiving a package with the information struct. Then check the quantity of packages received, file size are the same as the indicated on the struct.

The main problem I'm struggling with is that in the server the recv() is not getting all the data sent in some packages. For example, I tried with a text file which size is 14.3kB (it can be sent in 10 packages, where 9 of those would be 1460bytes and the final one of less than 1460bytes), but the first package received was of 528bytes, then 2 of 1460, then it would stop receiving at all.

Another thing I don't know how to do, is how to compare the file information struct when it's received by the server as it's converted to a char array now.

My code is as follows:

Client

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>    
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

#define  PORT_NUM           33333  // Port number used
#define  IP_ADDR "127.0.0.1" // IP address of server1 (*** HARDWIRED ***)
#define SOCKET_PROTOCOL 0

struct infoarchivo{
   unsigned long tamanio;
   unsigned long paquetes;
   char nombrearchivo[512];} info_tx,info_rx;

bool comparar(struct infoarchivo rx, struct infoarchivo tx);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 unsigned int         client_s;        // Descriptor del socket
 struct sockaddr_in   server_addr;     // Estructura con los datos del servidor
 struct sockaddr_in   client_addr;     // Estructura con los datos del cliente
 int                  addr_len;        // Tamaño de las estructuras
 char                 buf_tx[1460];    // Buffer de 1460 bytes para los datos a transmitir
 char                 ipserver[16];
 int                  bytesrecibidos,bytesaenviar, bytestx;               // Contadores
 int                  conectado; //variable auxiliar
 char                 nombre_archivo[512];
 long tamano_archivo,paquetes_archivo;
 char respuesta[3];
 bool flag,flag2;
 FILE * fp;
 int i;

 if (argc!=2)
   {
   printf("uso: clienteUDP www.xxx.yyy.zzz\n");
   return -1; 
   }
   strncpy(ipserver,argv[1],16);
 
 client_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOCKET_PROTOCOL);
 if (client_s==-1)
   {
   perror("socket");
   return 2;
   }
 printf("Cree el descriptor del socket %d\n",client_s);
 
 server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;            // Familia TCP/IP
 server_addr.sin_port        = htons(PORT_NUM);    // Número de Port, htons() lo convierte al orden de la red
 
 if  (inet_aton(ipserver, &server_addr.sin_addr)==0) // cargo la estructura con la dirección IP del servidor
   {
   printf ("La dirección  IP_ADDR no es una dirección IP válida. Programa terminado\n"); 
   return 3;
   }
 addr_len = sizeof(server_addr);
  
 conectado=connect(client_s, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
 if (conectado==-1)
   {
   perror("connect");
   return 4;
   }
    printf("El IP del servidor es: %s y el port del servidor  es %hu \n",inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr),
           ntohs(server_addr.sin_port));
 do{  
   printf("Ingrese ruta completa del archivo a transmitir:\n");
   scanf("%s", nombre_archivo); /*Consigo nombre del archivo a transmitir*/
   fp = fopen(nombre_archivo,"r");
   if(fp == NULL){
       perror("Error");
   return 0;
   }
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
   tamano_archivo = ftell(fp); /*tamano del archivo a transmitir*/
   rewind(fp);
   paquetes_archivo=ceil(tamano_archivo/1460)+1; /*cantidad de paquetes a enviar*/
   printf("%lu, %lu\n", tamano_archivo,paquetes_archivo);
   /*Envio informacion del archivo a transmitir*/
   info_tx.tamanio=tamano_archivo;
   info_tx.paquetes=paquetes_archivo;
   strcpy(info_tx.nombrearchivo,nombre_archivo);
   bytesaenviar=sizeof(info_tx);
   bytestx=send(client_s, &info_tx, bytesaenviar,0); 
   /*Espero confirmacion de lo recibido*/
   bytesrecibidos=recv(client_s, &info_rx, sizeof(info_rx), 0);
   flag = comparar(info_rx,info_tx); /*comparo las dos estructuras*/
   if(flag==true){ /*si son iguales*/
   if(paquetes_archivo>1){ /*envio archivo*/
       for(i=1;i<=paquetes_archivo-1;i++){ /*si tengo que enviar mas de 1 paquete envio n-1 de 1459 bytes*/
           fread(buf_tx,1460,1,fp);
           bytestx=send(client_s, buf_tx, bytesaenviar,0);
           printf("Envie paquete %d, que dice: %s\n",i,buf_tx);
           bzero(buf_tx,sizeof(buf_tx));
       }
   }
   fread(buf_tx,tamano_archivo-1460*(paquetes_archivo-1),1,fp); /*y un ultimo paquete de menos de 1459 bytes*/
   bytestx=send(client_s, buf_tx, bytesaenviar,0);
   printf("Envie el ultimo paquete, que dice: %s\n",buf_tx);
   /*VOLVER A ENVIAR, RECIBIR Y COMPARAR ESTRUCTURAS*/
       bytesaenviar=sizeof(info_tx);
       bytestx=send(client_s, &info_tx, bytesaenviar,0); 
   printf("Envie info del archivo\n");
       /*Espero confirmacion de lo recibido*/
       bytesrecibidos=recv(client_s, &info_rx, sizeof(info_rx), 0);
   printf("Recibí info del archivo\n");
       flag2 = comparar(info_rx,info_tx);
   printf("Compare info del archivo\n");
   if(flag2==true){
       printf("Envio finalizado con exito.\n");    
   }
   else{
       printf("%s",info_rx.nombrearchivo);
   }
   }
   else{
   printf("%s",info_rx.nombrearchivo);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   printf("¿Desea enviar otro archivo? (Si/No)\n");
   scanf("%s",respuesta);

 } while (strncmp(respuesta,"Si",2)==0); 
 
close(client_s);
printf("¡Hasta luego!\n");
return 0;
} // fin del programa    

bool comparar(struct infoarchivo rx,struct infoarchivo tx){
   if(rx.tamanio==tx.tamanio && rx.paquetes == tx.paquetes && strcmp(rx.nombrearchivo,tx.nombrearchivo)==0){
       return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

The server:

````
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#include <sys/types.h>    
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define  PORT_NUM           33333  // Port number used
#define  IP_ADDR "127.0.0.1" // IP address of server1 (*** HARDWIRED ***)
#define NCOLA 2
#define SOCKET_PROTOCOL 0

int terminar=0;
void handler(int sig);

struct infoarchivo{
    unsigned long tamanio;
    unsigned long paquetes;
    char nombrearchivo[512];} info_tx,info_rx;

bool comparar(char rx[],char buffer[], struct infoarchivo tx);
//===== Main program ========================================================
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  unsigned int         server_s;        // Descriptor del socket
  unsigned int         connect_s;       // Connection socket descriptor
  struct sockaddr_in   server_addr;     // Estructura con los datos del servidor
  struct sockaddr_in   client_addr;     // Estructura con los datos del cliente
  struct in_addr       client_ip_addr;  // Client IP address
  int                  addr_len;        // Tamaño de las estructuras
  char                 buf_tx[1460];    // Buffer de 1460 bytes para los datos a transmitir
  char                 buf_rx[1460];    // Buffer de 1460 bytes para los datos a recibir
  int                  bytesrecibidos, bytesaenviar, bytestx;  // Contadores
  int                  i=0;             //contador de mensajes
  int              salida;
  unsigned long        contador=0,bytestotales=0;
  char *cmd[] = {(char *)0};
  FILE * fp;
  pid_t pid_n;

  signal(SIGHUP,handler);

  // Crear el socket
  server_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOCKET_PROTOCOL);
  if (server_s==-1)
    {
    perror("socket");
    return 1;
    }
  printf("Cree el descriptor del socket %d\n",server_s);

  server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;            // Familia TCP/IP
  server_addr.sin_port        = htons(PORT_NUM);    // Número de Port, htons() lo convierte al orden de la red
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  // INADDR_ANY = cualquier direccion IP, htonl() lo convierte al orden de la red

  bind(server_s, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  
  printf("asocie el descriptor %u con el port %u acepta conexiones desde %u\n", server_s,PORT_NUM, INADDR_ANY) ;

  listen(server_s, NCOLA);
  addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
  while(1){   
    connect_s = accept(server_s, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);
    /* >>> paso #6 <<<
      Si llegué aca hubo un pedido de conexión
      Verifico que no haya retornado un error (-1)*/
    if (connect_s==-1)
      {
      perror("accept");
      return 2;
      }
    /* Acá voy a derivar la atención de la conexión a un proceso Hijo. En el hijo voy a cerrar el socket original 
    (server_s) porque no lo utiliza más, solo conserva abierto el socket connect_s  */
    fp = fopen("servidor.log","a+");
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *info;
    time(&rawtime);
    info = localtime( &rawtime );
    fprintf(fp, "%s %hu %s",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port),asctime(info));
    fclose(fp);

    if((pid_n=fork())==0){
    close (server_s); 
    printf("El hijo %d dice que el IP del cliente es: %s y el port del cliente es %hu \n",getpid(), inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
    bytesrecibidos=recv(connect_s, &info_rx, sizeof(info_rx), 0); //Espero que me llegue la información a recibir.
    printf("Recibi la info del archivo\n");
    if(bytesrecibidos==-1){
        strcpy(info_tx.nombrearchivo,"Error al recibir archivo\n");
        info_tx.paquetes=0;
        info_tx.tamanio=0;
        bytesaenviar=sizeof(info_tx);
        bytestx=send(connect_s, &info_tx, bytesaenviar,0); 
        printf("Error recibiendo informacion de archivo\n");
        close(connect_s);
        return 0; 
    }
    else{
        fp=fopen(info_rx.nombrearchivo,"w");
        if(fp!=NULL){ //Abri el archivo con exito
            //Vuelvo a enviar informacion
            strcpy(info_tx.nombrearchivo,info_rx.nombrearchivo);
            info_tx.paquetes=info_rx.paquetes;
            info_tx.tamanio=info_rx.tamanio;
            bytesaenviar=sizeof(info_tx);
            bytestx=send(connect_s, &info_tx, bytesaenviar,0);
            printf("Envie info del archivo\n");
        }
        else{ //Eror al abrir el archivo
            strcpy(info_tx.nombrearchivo,"Error al abrir archivo\n");
            info_tx.paquetes=0;
            info_tx.tamanio=0;
            bytesaenviar=sizeof(info_tx);
            bytestx=send(connect_s, &info_tx, bytesaenviar,0); 
            perror("Error: ");
            close(connect_s);
            return 1; 
        }

        sleep(1);
        bzero(buf_rx,sizeof(buf_rx));
        //Espero a recibir los paquetes
        do{
            
            bytesrecibidos=recv(connect_s, buf_rx, sizeof(buf_rx),MSG_WAITALL);
            if(bytesrecibidos==-1){perror("Di -1 porque: ");}
            printf("Recibi el paquete %ld, de tamaño %d, que dice: %s\n",contador+1,bytesrecibidos,buf_rx);
            fwrite(buf_rx,bytesrecibidos,1,fp);
            contador++;
            bytestotales=bytestotales+bytesrecibidos;
            bzero(buf_rx,sizeof(buf_rx));
        }while(contador<info_rx.paquetes);
        printf("Sali del while\n");
        if(bytestotales==info_rx.tamanio&&contador==info_rx.paquetes){
            strcpy(info_tx.nombrearchivo,info_rx.nombrearchivo);
            info_tx.paquetes=info_rx.paquetes;
            info_tx.tamanio=info_rx.tamanio;
            bytesaenviar=sizeof(info_tx);
            bytestx=send(connect_s, &info_tx, bytesaenviar,0);
            printf("Envie la info del archivo\n");
        }
        else{
            fclose(fp);
            remove(info_rx.nombrearchivo);
            strcpy(info_tx.nombrearchivo,"No coincide cantidad de paquetes recibidos o bytes recibidos\n");
            printf("No coincide cantidad de paquetes recibidos o bytes recibidos\n");
            printf("%lu, %lu, %lu, %lu",info_rx.tamanio,info_rx.paquetes,contador,bytestotales);
            info_tx.paquetes=contador;
            info_tx.tamanio=bytestotales;
            bytesaenviar=sizeof(info_tx);
            bytestx=send(connect_s, &info_tx, bytesaenviar,0);
        }
        printf("Termine de mandar todo\n");

    }

    close(connect_s);
    return 0; 
    }
    else{  // el else es el proceso PADRE
      printf("Soy el padre %d, recibi un pedido de conexión, la derive a mi hijo %d\n", getpid(),pid_n); 
      close(connect_s);
    } 
  }  //PADRE vuelve al accept a esperar otra conexión
  wait(NULL);
  close(server_s);
  return 0;
} 

void handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig==SIGHUP)
    {
    terminar=1;
    printf("señal HUP recibida, cuando establezca la proxima conexión el servidor terminará\n");
    }
} ```
````

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol - it doesn’t guarantee in any way that you will receive chunks the same size as those sent. Your code needs to handle that. This is why protocls built on TCP, such as HTTP,, delimit parts of the message with \n and send a length then the variable-length data.

Comment: So I should be checking the size of the received buffer until I get the full 1460 bytes I need? If so, How can I do that if using sizeof(buffer) will return 1460 as it is a predefined array?

Comment: Yes you should.

Comment: You also have to account for `send()` maybe not writing all the requested bytes in a single call.

Comment: You could also use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag.

Answer (score -1):

Let talk about TCP socket first.

When talking about TCP socket, **it's a stream of data.**
TCP views data as an unstructured, **but ordered, stream of bytes**. It's different from the kinds of socket.io.

From time to time, TCP will grab chunks of data from the send buffer and pass the data to the network layer. The maximum amount of data that can be grabbed and placed in a segment is limited by the maximum segment size (MSS). The MSS is typically set by first determining the length of the largest link-layer frame.

So it depends on the device.

For example, you have two messages, each of them has 1000 bytes data, and you call:

-------------- client side ----------------

```
client.send(theFirstMessage) // 1000 bytes
client.send(theSecondMessage) // 1000 bytes
```

-------------- server side -----------------

```
socket.onReceived(data => {
    // process(data)
})
```

With above pseudocode you should note that:

The data which received and called on onReceived block might not be 1000 bytes of theFirstMessage.

1. It could be first 400 bytes, then on other event you receive 400 bytes, then more 400 bytes (200 of the first one and 200 of the second one).
2. It could be 1200 bytes (1000 of the first one and 200 of the second one).

TCP views data as an unstructured, **but ordered, stream of bytes**. Socket.io is a wrapper, when it uses TCP socket, it collect and combine/split the data for you, so that you received the events with exactly the data was sent from other side.
When you work with TCP, you have to do it your self, you have to define the application protocol to do it.

There're two common ways to send/receive TCP requests:

1. **Splitter**, you choose a splitter. For example, we choose 32 bits AABBCCDD as the splitter (same as you choose END_DATA string), but keep in mind it's binary data. Then you have to ensure that the data in request doesn't contains the **splitter**. To do that, you have to encode the request. For example we can encode request as base64, then use the character which isn't included in base64 table as the splitter.
2. **Prefix length**, the above method has its overhead as we have to encode request data. The prefix length method is a better choice.
   We can prefix the length of request before.

The pseudocode:

```
// use Int32, 4 bytes to indicate the length of message after it

-------------- client side ----------------
    client.send(theFirstMessage.length)    // Int32
    client.send(theFirstMessage) // 1000 bytes

    client.send(theSecondMessage.length) 
    client.send(theSecondMessage) // 1000 bytes


-------------- server side -----------------

    var buffer = Buffer()

    socket.onReceived(data => {
        buffer.append(data)
        
        let length = Int32(buffer[0...3])
        
        if (buffer.length >= length + 4) {
           let theRequest = buffer[4 ... 4 + length - 1]
           process(theRequest)

           buffer = buffer.dropFirst(4 + length)
        }
       
    })
```

One more thing, when working with TCP socket, it's just stream of bytes, so the endianness is important https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

For example, an android device is little endian and server side (or other android device) is big endian. Then 4 bytes of Int32 from the android device, when received on server side, it will be decoded wrongly if you don't care about it.

So, the prefix length should be encoded by specific endianness.

Comment: 'The data which received and called on onReceived block couldn't be 1000 bytes of theFirstMessage': yes it could. Your other two possibilities can also occur, as could many others.

Comment: it looks like an English grammar problem. I suggest that you change "couldn't" to "might not"